# Why does this quicksort function not work?

Tags: quicksort, swap, comparator

```
void swap(Person* a, int i, int j) {
    Person b;
    b = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = b;
}


void quicksort(Person* a, int left, int right, PersonComparator cmp) {
    if (left >= right) return; // 0 or 1 elements, recursion end
    swap(a, left, (left + right) / 2); // move pivot element to left
    int j = left;
    for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        if (i < left) {
            swap(a, ++j, i);
    }
    // assert: v[i] < v[left] for i = left+1..j
}
swap(a, left, j); // move back pivot element
quicksort(a, left, j-1, cmp); // assert: v[i] < v[j] for i = left..j-1
quicksort(a, j+1, right, cmp); // assert: v[i] >= v[j] for i = j+1..right
}
```

I somehow have to get this "cmp" in there but I don't know where and how. Person* is a pointer to the struct Person btw.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to dump your homework questions

Comment: ok, do you know a place where I can dumb my homework questions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to use a debugger. Without that, you are lost. Run your code with a debugger and check where the code does something that you don't expect.

I suppose these lines:

```
for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
    if (i < left) {
```

won't do what you expect. It looks more like a question of "why would you think this might ever work", and not "why doesn't it work". Especially since you don't seem to be using the comparator at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think I am supposed to use a debugger at the moment. I know that the code doesn't work and that I didn't use the comparator at all as I pointed out in my question. i just have no idea how to build it in there. I guess I am just too stupid for programming.